# Pause audio playback when bluetooth speaker disconnects

Tags: audio, bluetooth, bluez, pipewire

I'm looking for a way to automatically pause audio when the Bluetooth speaker I'm playing audio on disconnects. I've seen this feature on Android, and I'd like to have it on my desktop as well.

Here are the details of my system:

- **Operating System:** openSUSE Tumbleweed 20231219
- **Desktop Environment:** KDE Plasma Version 5.27.10
- **KDE Frameworks Version:** 5.113.0
- **Qt Version:** 5.15.11
- **Kernel Version:** 6.6.6-1-default (64-bit)
- **Graphics Platform:** Wayland
- **CPU:** 8 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11300H @ 3.10GHz
- **RAM:** 15.4 GiB
- **Graphics Processor:** Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics
- **Laptop Model:** HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-dk2xxx
- **Pipewire Version:** 1.0.0
- **Bluez Version:** 5.70

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!